# Efficient way to get all map values whose keys match a criterion

Tags: java, dictionary

I have following map `Map<IndexDerivedKey, Collection<Data<D>>> indexedData` in an indexable data structure.

`IndexDerivedKey` conforms to an `Index`, an index consists of keys and corresponding values. The keys are used to extract the values from the elements in the indexable data structure.

For example there's an index, which consists of the keys `firstName` and `lastName`, we use this index to extract values from objects, which possess these attributes, this operation yields an `IndexDerivedKey` per object.

That `IndexDerivedKey` contains the mapping from above keys to their respective values and is used to store the objects in the map `indexedData`, which I mentioned before. The map value is a collection type, since it is possible for several objects to be equal (with respect to the index).

**QUESTION**
How can I extract all objects with `firstName = "John"`, hereby ignoring the value of `lastName`. Obviously I can iterate over all keys and check the value of `firstName` in `O(n)`.

But since the `IndexDerivedKey` `{firstName = "John"}` is a subset of all other keys with `firstName = "John"`, e.g. `{firstName = "John", lastName = "Smith"}`, I suppose there has to be a more efficient way. Maybe utilizing a `TreeSet`?

---

1

```
  public IndexDerivedKeyImpl(Index index, Map<String, String> keyValues)
  {
    this.keyValues = keyValues;
    this.index = index;

    for (String key : keyValues.keySet())
      if (!index.supportsKey(key))
        throw new IndexKeyMismatchException(key, index);
  }
```

2

```
  // in data.Index.index(Indexable)
  @Override
  public IndexDerivedKey index(Indexable data)
  {
    Map<String, String> keyValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    IndexDerivedKey key = new IndexDerivedKeyImpl(this, keyValues);

    for (String k : keys)
    {
      String value = data.get(k);
      if (value != null)
        keyValues.put(k, value);
    }

    return key;
  }
```

Comment: I don't see a way where it can be done in order less than n using HashMap, since there is no way you know which keys start with firstName = "X".
If fetching data with firstName is your only criteria, a Treeset will definitely help. But if you criteria for fetching information from HashMap keeps on changing, maintaining so many data structures is not a good idea.

Comment: This isn't the point of a `map`...a map is designed to have a unique key associated with a value.  Each key must be unique if you are trying to bring back multiple values based upon 1 key that won't work.  What you could do is have the key be `firstName` then the value a `list` of your `objects` that all have the same `firstName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search is always on a specific order, make a key class with a Comparable, and equals.

And then use a `SortedMap`, like `TreeMap`. This is *navigable* too. You might for instance use [subMap(fromKey, toKey)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#subMap-K-K-)

Comment: That's the direction I was aiming for. This approach demands that the keys of the index are prioritized `firstName < lastName < ...`, which shouldn't be a problem. But what are appropiate keys, if I'm searching for `firstName =  "John"`?  Maybe `firstName = "John" lastName = "a"` and `firstName = "John" lastName = "Z"`?

Comment: Or I could create two global keys MIN/MAX which are always smaller or bigger than the value they compare against and are used to set unset values in the `fromKey` and `toKey`.

Comment: That's what I did in the end. I created two String objects (no String literals) that represent min/max and checked for object identity against those values in the compareTo method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your `Map` with an other key, you are better off using an other `Map`:

```
Map<String, Collection<Data<D>>> dataByFirstName = // ...
```

Where the keys are the first names.

Comment: I would have to create a map for every combination of keys in the index (resp. for every element in the powerset of keys, except the empty set).